# MVC + WebApi. Авторизация и аутентификация

Tags: asp.net-mvc, авторизация, asp.net-web-api, аутентификация

Есть проект `MVC` и отдельно проект `WebApi`. Доступ к базе данных полностью реализовывается через WebApi (в том числе и авторизация и аутентификация). То есть в данном случае MVC - клиент, WebApi - сервер.

Встал вопрос как грамотно реализовать авторизацию и аутентификацию в MVC проекте (на стороне клиента). Я много перечитал как это реализовывается в WebApi (через токен), но не могу понять как грамотно использовать этот токен в MVC.

Делать обертку к каждому запросу? Не знаю также как определить роль пользователя в MVC. Может есть какая то возможность переделать стандартные методы MVC авторизации для работы с токеном? Будут ли работать атрибуты `Autorize` на стороне клиента MVC? Ткните пожалуйста в какой то пример такой реализации если можно, либо подскажите как лучше это реализовать.

Comment: В asp.net identity все есть

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "все есть"? Можно более развернутый ответ?

Comment: В ASP.NET Identity уже определена инфраструктура для работы с пользователями и ролями.Есть методы по генерации и проверки токенов(в случае смены пароля, либо его восстановления). Непонятно что у вас не получается. И почему вы считаете, что MVC - это сторона клиента? Запросы также приходят и обрабатываются на сервере

Comment: Возможно я неправильно пояснил. Значит у меня ДВА ОТДЕЛЬНЫХ проекта. Один из них - WebApi. Только он общается с базой данных. MVC - с базой общается только через Web Api. Встроенная в MVC реализация ASP.NET Identity предусматривает общение с базой данных напрямую. А мне надо ТОЛЬКО что б через Web Api.

Comment: Неважно обращается ли к бд или нет, там может быть другая задача, к примеру работа с кэшем